# Как вывести элемент из массива?

Tags: php

Я новичок в php. 
Это ответ на запрос в JSON формате:

```
{
    "data": {
        "rests": [
            {
                "id": 386410001,
                "name": "Ресторан \"123\"",
                "address": "Пр. Третий 63, К \"Солнце\"",
                "country": "Казахстан",
                "city_name": "Астана",
                "status": "Active",
                "min_check_amount": 3000,
                "delivery_period": {
                    "begin": "9:00",
                    "end": "23:00"
                },
                "delivery_price": 0
            }
        ]
    },
    "ver": "1.3.0.27",
    "timestamp": "2019-07-01T13:39:54",
    "status": "Ok",
}
```

Как сделать так, чтобы мне вывело поле country?
Т.е сделать так, чтобы бы на выводе было 'Казахстан'?
Не ругайтесь, знаю, вопрос легкий, просто очень сложно сформулировать мысль для поиска.

Comment: Array ( [data] => Array ( [rests] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 386410001 [name] => Ресторан "Korona" [address] => Пр. Третий 63, К "Солнце" [country] => Казахстан [city_name] => Астана [status] => Active [min_check_amount] => 3000 [delivery_period] => Array ( [begin] => 9:00 [end] => 23:00 ) [delivery_price] => 0 ) ) ) [ver] => 1.3.0.27 [timestamp] => 2019-07-01T13:43:49 [status] => Ok [requestId] => 7afbd194b0b34e4f94be7c340851a34a )

Вот что выводит в браузере.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если у вас ассоциативный массив:

```php
echo $result['data']['rests'][0]['country'];
```

Если у вас объект:

```php
echo $result->data->rests[0]->country;
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое!